# Is there a math parser for petitparser?

Tags: dart, petitparser

is there a dart lib that can parse math strings such as `(3+4)/4.5`?
I tried to build a basic parser with petitparser, but I am in over my head and its just trial and error right now :) Is there an petitparser (Dart or any other language) implementation of a simple math parser somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [introductory tutorial](http://jenkins.lukas-renggli.ch/job/PetitParserDart/javadoc/petitparser.html) of PetitParser for Dart explains building a simple expression grammar in the section "Writing a More Complicated Grammar".

There is a more complicated expression grammar in the [test suite](https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser/blob/master/petitparser/test/expression_test.dart) of PetitParser for Dart, that can help you get started.

The Smalltalk implementation of PetitParser has even more examples. Also it includes a factory object that helps you building expression grammars. <strike>Unfortunately this code hasn't been ported yet.</strike>

**Update:** As of version 1.1.0 PetitParser includes a factory for [building expression grammars](https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser/blob/master/petitparser/lib/src/expression/builder.dart).