# Dart - Split String by RegEx

Tags: regex, dart, lex

I am trying to split a string like this:

```
x^-5 - 3
```

into a list like this:

```
[x^-5, -, 3]
```

The first minus after the ^ must be at the same list index as the x, because it's just the negative exponent. However, I want other minuses, which are not an exponent of anything, to be on their own index.

When splitting by -, obviously my x^-5 gets split into two as well.

So is there any way I can achieve this using RegEx or something like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try splitting with whitespace? `.split(new RegExp(r"\s+"))`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it should work without whitespace... But If I don't find another solution, I'll stick to whitespace, thanks.

Comment: It turns out, in Dart, you cannot use a JS approach to capture subpatterns to return with the split chunks. You'd better write a parser or use any ready-made libraries.

Comment: Okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use [`allMatches`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.23.0/dart-core/RegExp/allMatches.html) instead of `split`, you can use a pattern like this:

```
(?:\^\s*-|[^\-])+|-
```

[Working example: DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/15c1094bf85bc043b3677295fc79f0f2)

- We match tokens that consist of anything except `-`, or `^-`.
- If we reach a `-` that is not an exponent, we match it alone, similar to a split.

Some notes:

- There are similar patterns, this may not be the most efficient, but it is short.
- If you are matching mathematical expressions, there are many things that can go wrong (for example parentheses), regular expressions are not a good way to achieve that.
- This is basically the [match to skip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/7586) trick.

Comment: In other languages you could've used a lookbehind, [`(?<!\^)-`](https://regex101.com/r/2vlDCy/1), but that isn't supported on JavaScript (and Dart).

Comment: Wow, awesome. Exactly what I was looking for, thank you :)

Comment: Btw what would you use instead of regex?

Comment: @Rechunk - For example, in JavaScript, I found a library called Math.js, that can parse expressions: http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html#parse . For Dart, there's this: [Is there a math parser for petitparser?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18924498/7586), and [math_expressions (beta)](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/math_expressions)

Comment: how would I extend this regex to be able to split something like this:

x^-5 + 3

(with a plus)
into this:

[x^-5, +, 3]?

Comment: @Rechunk - That's pretty simple. You need to change all places you have `-` to also accept `+`. For example (also with `*` and `/`): `(?:[\^*/]\s*[\-+]|[^\-+])+|[\-+]` - [example](https://regex101.com/r/O2QaDh/1)